# Generic way to parse different date formats

Tags: regex, perl

I have several different date formats to parse, for example:

```
$date1 = '^(\d\d),(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)'; # DD,MM HH:MM:SS
$date2 = '^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)'; # YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I want to be left with the variables

```
($year, $day, $month, $hour, $minute, $second)
```

to be populated correctly. I can capture the first date format in Perl with a pattern like:

```
($day, $month, $hour, $minute, $second) = $log_line =~ /$date1/;
$year = current_year; # guess as date format has no year value
```

But to capture the second date, I would need to rearrange the order of the variables. I don't want to hardcode in the ordering for each type of date, but I know the info has to be contained somewhere.

I want this program to be scalable and maintainable; is there a simple solution for my program to adapt to the different formats?

EDIT: I realise the ordering has to be stored somewhere, I'm looking for the most concise option for doing this.

Comment: you have to hardcode the order - how else would you decode the date??

Comment: I was thinking of linking the regex with an ordering string like "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" but then you'd need to parse that to rearrange the variables. You think the best option is to hardcode in the order for each? I'm trying to keep it simple for others to add new date formats.

Comment: Yes, you could do that - but then one character per variable is enough...  You could also add it directly to the regex, that is, `'^(YYYY)-(MM)-(DD) (HH):(mm):(SS)'` (notice the distinction between M and m), and from that both fetch the order, and generate the regex.

Comment: "I don't want to hardcode in the ordering for each type of date" You have to. How could a program accurately guess that `11,01` represents January 11 and not November 1? That's not a standard date format.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve you immediate problem with named capture groups:

```
if ( $str =~ /(?<year>\d\d\d\d)-(?<month>\d\d)-(?<day>\d\d)/ ) {
  $year = $+{year};
  $month = $+{month};
  $day = $+{day};
}
```

Your more general problem is best addressed with the various DateTime::Format modules from cpan.

Answer (score 1):

You can use core [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module to parse dates,

```
use Time::Piece;

my @arr = (
  Time::Piece->strptime(Time::Piece->new->year ."01,02 13:24:01", "%Y%d,%m %H:%M:%S"),
  Time::Piece->strptime("2015-02-01 13:24:01", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
);

for my $t (@arr) {
  my ($year, $day, $month, $hour, $minute, $second) = 
    ($t->year, $t->mday, $t->mon, $t->hour, $t->min, $t->sec);

  print "$year, $day, $month, $hour, $minute, $second\n";
}
```